# get object of specific class in Angular from c# api

Tags: c#, angular, model, mapping

I have c# class test1

```
public class test1
    {
        public int testID{ get; set; }
        public string testName{ get; set; }
        public int testValue{ get; set; }
}
```

In Angular I have testService which has function getObject

```
  getObject(param) {    
      return this.http.post(appSettings.BackEndUrl + '/getObject?testID='+param,'');     
    }
```

In Angular I also made same type class

```
export class test1Model{
    testID: Number;
    testName: String;
    testValue: Number;
}
```

Now In some component I want to create variable

```
testObjVariable: test1Model;
```

And put that api data inside it.
I'm trying to do it this way

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.testObjVariable = this.testService.getObject(this.testID);
  }
```

And I get error

> Type 'Observable' is missing the following properties from
>   type 'test1Model': testID, testName, testValue

Despite the fact that teoretically I'm transfering just exactly those type of data. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Adrita Sharma solution but in order to get rid of that error, You may need to add return type to your typescript function like this:

**Solution#1:**

```
getObject(param) : Observable<test1Model> {    
  return this.http.post(appSettings.BackEndUrl + '/getObject?testID='+param,'');     
}
```

or

```
getObject(param) {    
  return this.http.post<test1Model>(appSettings.BackEndUrl + '/getObject?testID='+param,'');     
}
```

**Solution#2:** you can have something like this where you are assigning to variable

```
   ngOnInit() {
      this.testService.getObject(this.testID).subscribe((data: test1Model) => {
        this.testObjVariable = data
      });
   }
```

because by default typescript function is returning `Observable<test1Model>` object, that is not assignable to `test1Model` type. I hope this make sense to you.

Comment: none of the above helps :( when I try to console.log I get "undefined". At the same time from the c# log I see that data is going...

Answer (score 1):

You need to `subscribe` the http call

Try like this:

```
ngOnInit() { 

  this.testService.getObject(this.testID).subscribe((data:test1Model) => {
   this.testObjVariable = data
  });
}
```

Comment: That added new error
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

After some thinking I've tryied to declare 
testObjVariable as any. In that case errors gone, but when I test application I get Cannot read property 'testName' of undefined

Comment: @david Refer to this Solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/58748009/6412916

Comment: @David Just add `data:test1Model `